# How to check content of 2 similar file?

Tags: phpstorm

Have PhpStorm 2021 functionality to check content of 2 similar files(left and right panel),  with lines comparing like
in Local History ?

Thank you!

Comment: PhpStorm --> Help --> **Compare files** : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/comparing-files-and-folders.html#twofiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the simplest approach I've discovered to compare a project file with a non-project file is to copy the external file to the clipboard and then select ***"View->Compare with clipboard."***

Shortcut:
**For Windows -> CTRL+D**

Comment: You can compare files present in the Project View panel: just select them: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/comparing-files-and-folders.html#twofiles